# Azure B2C Performance Metrics

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-monitoring

Is it possible to track page load times for each user journey? What other performance metrics are available for Azure B2C that we can also plugin to Azure Monitor? Can we track total time of execution for a user journey (at least the steps where we do not wait for user input)

Answer (score 0):

Came across this github.com/yoelhor/aadb2c-load-test which might help to perform Azure AD B2C Load Testing.